# Why width of div is different for select box and textbox?

Tags: html, css

[image]This is a code which i am using in my page

### html

```
<div class="dec">
<select>
    <option selected="selected" value="0">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="-1">3</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<input name="im_q" id="im_q" type="text" class="dec" placeholder="Texto a Buscar" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Texto a Buscar'" />
</div>
```

### css

```
.dec select {
padding-top: 5px;
width: 108%;
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
background: transparent;
background-image: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
background-image:url('carat-d-black.png');
background-position:90% 70%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
.dec {
 border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #BBBBBB;
height: 35px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 99.5%;
 }
```

I am using same css for select and for textbox.The problem is when we vary(reduce) the size of window,the selectbox size is smaller than the textbox.But i want same size for both.
Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/f7pGV/

Please any one help me.

Comment: Looks fine for me on chrome.. can you provide a screenshot and also tell us on which browser you are testing. (also version)

Comment: I have added image and i am using mozill 30.0 and observer it carefully.

Comment: both are having same size.

Comment: I suppose the problem is the following: You are setting `width:108%`, presumably to push the default arrow out, so you can add a custom arrow. That means that your dropdown will have a width of... well... `108%`. Is that surprising?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have added the class 'dec' to a div containing Select and then the same class to the input rather than the container div.

Change the structure to

```
   <div class="dec">
      <select>
       <option selected="selected" value="0">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="-1">3</option>
     </select>
 </div>
 <div class="dec">
    <input name="im_q" id="im_q" type="text"  placeholder="Texto a Buscar" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Texto a Buscar'" />
</div>
```

And add this to the css

```
.dec input{
   width:100%;
   height:100%
 }
```

Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f7pGV/2/

Comment: Please mark the answer as right so that it will be removed from the Unanswered queue of Stackoverflow.